# List points within a certain radius of a location?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, location, radius

I'm making an API for an iPhone app. Put simply, I have locations stored in a database (Lat/long). When a user send a request for points within, let's say, a five (5) mile radius, I'll need to make use of an algorithm to only give me those points from a MySQL database.

1. How can I convert miles to minutes in a coordinate? IE, with the tapering nature of longitude in mind, how much do I add to coordinates I'm searching through to compare to the users location?

2 What's a good formula to take into account the way longitude/latitude changes as you go to different points of Earth?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'd say: stop there and look at [`Google Maps API`](https://developers.google.com/maps/). I mean, it is there for a reason.

Comment: Concerning geocoordinates, the most accurate way to determine the distance ist not some euklidean distance, but the great circle distance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Answer (score 0):

You never mentioned how you stored the data, so I can't give you the actual code. Here's just something I came up with:

1. Import all the data into some efficient database. Optimize it to be efficient at pulling up coordinates within a certain X/Y range
2. Select all the coordinates within a 10x10 mile square. Import them into an array
3. Use a `foreach` to go through that array and use the distance formula (`distance=sqrt((x-x)^2+(y-y)^2)`). If within 5 miles, add it to another array. If not, ignore it.

I don't know how efficient this would be with thousands of coordinates in a small location; you might have to fine tune it (for example, try a smaller box first if you're finding the closest location).

I do have to agree with Darren that Google Maps API might be better suited, although I haven't used it before.